# Python Tensorflow for image approval system

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I've been dabbling around with machine learning and tensorflow, and have successfully used a github repo to solve captchas. Now I want go a step further.

I already have a dataset(and its still growing), of images that are labeled 1 or 0, based on if it was approved or not. (Approved=1)

I want to use machine learning, to learn from what was approved and denied, and make a prediction based on new incoming images. My issue is however, that I'm not sure what kind of neural network I would need for this, nor how to research such thing.

If you guys have any references that could aid me in, or if you know, what kind of neural network setup I need to begin this machine learned approval system?

Answer (score 0):

You gonna need a huge dataset for such task.

The neural network that you are looking for is Convolutional Neural Network (CNN).

If you are completely new to CNN, then I recommend you looking at [this](https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/) article.

The article will give you an idea of what is CNN, how it works, what is filter and pooling, etc...

Comment: How huge a dataset? Currently have about 20K examples(10K approved, 10K denied).

Comment: Can you describe how an image can be denied and how it can be approved? Like what are you trying to _classify_ in specific?

Comment: 1920 by 1080 JPG images, sent in as submissions via phone. Ideally, the machine learning approval system would change depending on who used it, because it is by personal preference(no science or sure fire way to describe approval/denial).

The pictures could be of cool cars, people, shows, etc(basically anything).

Comment: Yea, you will need to use CNN

Comment: So is CNN a category of neural networks? Or is it a type of neural network(already designed)?

Comment: And would I need more than two confolutional layer and two fully connected layers?

Comment: It depends on what architecture you choose to use

Comment: By architecture are you referring to hardware?